# Homeomorphic surfaces embedded in 4-space

Tags: knot-theory, low-dimensional-topology, knot-invariants

A surface-knot is a closed connected surface embedded in the Euclidean 4-space $\mathbb{R}^4$. We consider the projection of the surface-knot into $\mathbb{R}^3$ with the singularity set contains of at most three types: double points, triple points or branch points.  Let $F$ and $F'$ be two homeomorphic surfaces embedded both in 4-space so that their projections have same singularity set. I am asking whether the two projections are isotopy in 3-space or not, I.e the two surface-knots are equivalent or not.